# Access Denied when Accessing another server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

My application is hosted in **192.14.14.22** server and trying to get a list of file names from another directory in **192.14.253.25** D drive and this is where we get **Access Denied** Issue but I'm able to access **//192.14.253.25/d$** from run command.I know this is a frequent question but my query is to know how to access the files as I'm able to access it from my PC and from the run but not from the application.Below is my code.

```
[NonAction]
        public List<FilesListDTO> GetList()
        {
            List<FilesListDTO> lstFiles = null;

            try
            {
                lstFiles = new List<FilesListDTO>();

                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@'//192.14.253.25/d$');

                lstFiles = dir.GetFiles().OrderBy(x => x.FullName).Select(x => new FilesListDTO
                {
                    Filename = x.FullName.Replace(CDMSServerPath, string.Empty),
                    DateModified = x.CreationTimeUtc
                }).OrderByDescending(c => c.DateModified).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Util.WriteLog("GetList Error:" + ex.Message);
            }

            return lstFiles;
        }
```

Comment: Is the application running under your own account or a service user? If not your own, you need to give that account permissions to the server, probably admin rights as you are using the hidden drive share.

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas I have added the key for impersonate
<identity impersonate="false" userName="vcvcplicationrobot" password="xxxxxx"/>

Comment: @Rhumborl both the servers are under admin access and belong to same company where i work

Comment: @sainath can you check the directorys' share permissions? maybe there is something in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using below key in web config

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="vcvcplicationrobot" password="xxxxxx"/>
```